# Google Quick Scroll extension for Safari

Tags: safari, search, safari-extensions, google

There is a great Chrome extension Google Quick Scroll that scrolls to funded text on a page after googling it. I want it for Safari but cannot find any alternatives or so. Is there?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the Google Quick Scroll but it works as well.

The <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> will open the search window, type or copy the text in it.

Comment: That's actually exactly what the plugin does as far I can see, nice catch.

Comment: I'm doing it every time already. I just bored and want to automate my work.